# Pointers and Polymorphism

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism

I have problems understanding the following C++ code. Can somebody please explain to me the meaning of the line 3? What does ": lmp(ptr)" before constructer mean?

I cannot make sense out of it

```
class Pointers {
 public:
  Pointers(TYPE* ptr) : lmp(ptr)
    {}
  virtual ~Pointers() {}
 protected:
  TYPE* lmp;
};

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 : lmp(ptr)
```

is called `constructor initialization list`. It will initialize `lmp` with `ptr`.
 See this link for some understanding: [What is constructor initialization list and why should I use it](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?464084-C-General-What-is-the-initialization-list-and-why-should-I-use-it)